# is there a way in android studio to call a single activity from couple of other activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

please help .
Im trying to get access to one specific activity from two other activity so I wont write multiple code .
I send from those different activities the same type of "putExtra" but with different values to identify the source of the activity it came from.

I would like if someone could tell me what Im doing wrong.

Sorry and thanks in advance ...

Comment: is your only concern to check which activity invokes your common activity?

Comment: Please first check the AS documentation and rephrase your question including the problematic configuration, so that others can see/help pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

**Activity1**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, DestinationActivity.class)
i.putExtra("OriginActivity", "Act1")
startActivity(i)
```

**Activity2**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, DestinationActivity.class)
i.putExtra("OriginActivity", "Act2")
startActivity(i)
```

**DestinationActivity**

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras != null) {

        if(extras.getString("OriginActivity").equals("Act1")){
            // you came from Activity 1

        }else if(extras.getString("OriginActivity").equals("Act2")){
            // you came from Activity 2
        }
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send extra values to identify the calling `Activity`, there's a method called `getCallingActivity()` which can help you.

But it would only return a non null value if you have invoked your `Activity` through `startActivityForResult()`

Here is the sample code:

```
ComponentName callingActivity = getCallingActivity();
if (callingActivity != null)
{
    String activityName = callingActivity.getShortClassName();
    if (activityName.endsWith("INVOKING_ACTIVITY_NAME"))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```